# Message loop with predefined number of iterations in Erlang

Tags: erlang, distributed, distributed-computing

Suppose that I have 3 processes, each of which is registered so that I can send and receive messages in an easy way.

How can I create a loop that runs for, say, 10 iterations and sends messages forwards and backwards between process 1 and 3, going through process 2? Meaning, I would like process 1 to send a message to process 2, which should send it to process 3 and viceversa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a small module to do what you are looking for. But as I see that you are looking for many answers, I guess you are new to erlang. So I think you should look at books or on-line books to start your learning curve. My preferred one is:
http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content
The author did a great job to help beginners to start with Erlang. When you will be getting more familiar with erlang, the official documentation is very interesting too (although it doesn't help to start!).

```
-module(ping3).
-compile(export_all).

% Launch 3 loops, init phase
start() ->
    P1 = spawn(?MODULE,loop,[]),
    P2 = spawn(?MODULE,loop,[]),
    P3 = spawn(?MODULE,loop,[]),
    {P1,P2,P3}.

% user interface
start_ring(P1,P2,P3,Loop) ->
    P1 ! {start,P2,P3,Loop}.

% kind of server, the messages content the informations about what to do, and all needed parameters
% it implements your protocol
loop() ->
    receive
        {start,By,To,Loop} ->
            Ref = make_ref(),
            io:format("start ring for ~p iterations of ~p~n",[Loop,Ref]),
            By ! {go_via,Ref,self(),By,To,Loop},
            loop();
        {go_via,Ref,From,By,To,Loop} ->
            To ! {go,Ref,From,By,To,Loop},
            loop();
        {go,Ref,From,By,To,Loop} ->
            By ! {back_via,Ref,From,By,To,Loop},
            loop();
        {back_via,Ref,From,By,To,Loop} ->
            To ! {back,Ref,From,By,To,Loop},
            loop();
        {back,Ref,_,_,_,0} ->
            io:format("end of ring of ~p~n",[Ref]),
            loop();
        {back,Ref,From,By,To,Loop} ->
            io:format("continue ring for ~p iterations of ~p~n",[NewLoop=Loop-1,Ref]),
            By ! {go_via,Ref,From,By,To,NewLoop},
            loop();
        stop -> bye
    end.
```

and in the shell:

```
(exec@WXFRB1824L)48> {P1,P2,P3} = ping3:start().
{<0.93.0>,<0.94.0>,<0.95.0>}
(exec@WXFRB1824L)49> ping3:start_ring(P1,P2,P3,20),ping3:start_ring(P2,P1,P3,15).     
start ring for 20 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
start ring for 15 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
{start,<0.93.0>,<0.95.0>,15}
continue ring for 19 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 14 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 18 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 13 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 17 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 12 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 16 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 11 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 15 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 10 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 14 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 9 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 13 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 8 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 7 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 6 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 5 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 4 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 3 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 2 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 1 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 0 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
end of ring of #Ref<0.0.1.91080>
continue ring for 12 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 11 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 10 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 9 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 8 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 7 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 6 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 5 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 4 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 3 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 2 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 1 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
continue ring for 0 iterations of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
end of ring of #Ref<0.0.1.91077>
(exec@WXFRB1824L)50>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I am a beginner, but quite frankly I must say that the online documentation about Erlang is one of the worst I have ever seen, so I prefer to ask some questions here and award reputation points ;)

Comment: you are right, the documentation is not made to help people to start. I read somewhere that it is the Erricson internal doc, so done for people who have seen the birth of erlang :o). But the link I gave you is really a great one. Most of the topics you need to start are reviewed in a step by step approach. I read it entirely and still continue to go there when I am wondering about program architecture.

Comment: I will keep looking at it then :) In the meantime, feel free to help me with my other questions :D

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a function which does whatever you tell it to `N` times:

```
times(0, Fun) -> ok;
times(N, Fun) -> Fun(), times(N - 1, Fun).
```

Then call it in the code for process 1:

```
times(10, fun() -> process2 ! SomeMessage end)
```

And code for process 2 will need to know that to handle this message, e.g. send something to process 3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) what do you mean with the last sentence though?